# How to automatically remove shared_ptr from Singleton Manager class at the end of scope of its creation

Tags: c++

I have a Singleton `ButtonManager` that holds a vector of `Button` objects. The `ButtonManager` subject exists because it distributes the events to all of the `Button` observers when `HandleEvents` is called. It needs to be a Singleton for some other reasons.

My problem is that I'd like to remove the need for my `Button` to have to remove themselves from my `ButtonManager` manually. Ideally, at the end of the scope where I `Create` a `Button`, the ButtonManager would also lose its reference to it.

```
class ButtonManager : public EventHandler
{
public:
   static ButtonManager & Instance();

public:
   // push_back a Button to the vector and return it
   std::shared_ptr<Button> Create(const Rect & _rect, const std::string _text, const Colour & _fg, const Colour & _bg);

   // Erase the button pointer from the vector
   void Remove(const std::shared_ptr<Button> & _button);

   // EventHandler
   void HandleEvents( const Event & _event );

   ...

private:
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Button>> buttons;
};

class Button : public EventHandler
{
public:
   Button(const Rect & _rect, const std::string & _text, const Colour & _fg, const Colour & _bg);

   ...

   // EventHandler
   void HandleEvents( const Event & _event );
};
```

Current scenario:

```
{
   std::shared_ptr<Button> ok_button_ptr = UI::ButtonManager::Instance().Create(UI::Rect(5, 5, 5, 1), string("OK"), UI::Colour::White, UI::Colour::DodgerBlue);

   // events are processed and distributed to the buttonmanager 
   // which then distributes to the buttons

   UI::ButtonManager::Instance().Remove(ok_button_ptr);
}
```

Ideal scenario:

```
{
   std::shared_ptr<Button> ok_button_ptr = UI::ButtonManager::Instance().Create(UI::Rect(5, 5, 5, 1), string("OK"), UI::Colour::White, UI::Colour::DodgerBlue);

   // events are processed and distributed to the buttonmanager 
   // which then distributes to the buttons

   // ok_button_ptr loses its reference here and the ButtonManager erase's the shared_ptr as well if it holds the last reference to the Button
}
```

Comment: I don't fully get your question. Isn't the whole point of a `std::shared_ptr<>` you don't have to care about the memory management for your `Button` instances?? Or what exactly do you do with `Remove()`?

Comment: The problem is that because ButtonManager is a Singleton, it would never destroy a Button unless asked. I've made some edits to clarify. Remove simply finds and erases the shared_ptr from the vector.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible with the std::shared_ptr... We have our own implementation of smart_ptr that has similar functionality, We're able to define a *hook*, an object function that will be executed when the object is about to be deleted by the shared_ptr (i.e. when all references are gone). We use that functionality to return the object to a pool, after executing some reset() methods...

Comment: So essentially I'm looking at a custom smart ptr that will execute Remove on my button ManagerButton when there's one reference left?

Comment: jsantander's custom smart pointer suggestion lead me to the correct solution which is to use a weak_ptr as it is non-owning.

Answer (score 1):

Freeing resources at scope-exit can be done with RAII. Create a ButtonHolder class which holds the shared_ptr as a member and calls Remove in its destructor

```
class ButtonHolder
{
public:
    ButtonHolder(std::shared_ptr<Button> b): theButton(std::move(b)) {}
    ~ButtonHolder() {
        UI::ButtonManager::Instance().Remove(theButton);
    }

    // could give it shared_ptr interface, e.g.
    Button& operator*() const;
    Button& operator->() const;
    // etc
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Button> theButton;
};

{
   // get button from singleton. Ref count increases by one. Let's say it is now 2.
   ButtonHolder ok_button_ptr( UI::ButtonManager::Instance().Create(...) );

   // events are processed and distributed to the buttonmanager 
   // which then distributes to the buttons

   // ButtonHolder::~ButtonHolder is called which removes the button from the 
   // singleton (ref count = 1) and then deletes its own shared_ptr member (ref count = 0)
   // to delete the button object completely
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. This would work. However it's even better to use std::vector<std::weak_ptr> as it does not hold a reference and the lifetime is then related to the shared_ptrs created from it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the Lapsed listener problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapsed_listener_problem

The solution is to use a `vector` of `weak_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` because a `weak_ptr` is a non-owning smart pointer.

```
  class ButtonManager : public IUIObservable
   {
   public:
      static ButtonManager & Instance();
      void Subscribe(const std::shared_ptr<IUIObservable> & _o);
      void HandleEvents( const sf::Event & _event );

      ...

   private:
      std::vector<std::weak_ptr<IUIObservable>> observers;
   };



   void ButtonManager::Subscribe(const std::shared_ptr<IUIObservable> & _o)
   {
      observers.push_back(_o);
   }

   void ButtonManager::HandleEvents( const sf::Event & _event )
   {
        // Remove any dead observers. These are the ones that have expired().
        this->observers.erase(std::remove_if(this->observers.begin(), this->observers.end(),
            [](const std::weak_ptr<IUIObservable>& _element)
        {
            return _element.expired();
        }), this->observers.end());

      // go through all the elements and handle events
      for (auto& observer_weak_ptr : this->observers)
      {
         auto observer_ptr = observer_weak_ptr.lock();
         if (observer_ptr)
         {
            observer_ptr->HandleEvents(_event);
         }
      }
   }
```

Usage example:

```
  auto ok_button = std::make_shared<Button>(UI::Rect(5, 5, 5, 1), string("OK"), UI::Colour::White, UI::Colour::DodgerBlue);

  UI::ButtonManager::Instance().Subscribe(ok_button);

  {
     auto tmp_button = std::make_shared<Button>(UI::Rect(6, 5, 5, 1), string("Tmp"), UI::Colour::White, UI::Colour::DodgerBlue);

     UI::ButtonManager::Instance().Subscribe(tmp_button);
     // tmp_button will be expired on the next process events
  }

  // Process Events
```